# For a group $G$: show that $p$ is a divisor of $\# \mathcal{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Given a prime number $p$, an integer $n>0$, and a group $G$, where $\#G=p^n$.

Let $\mathcal{Z}(G)$ the center of the group: $\mathcal{Z}(G)G= \{a\in G; xa=ax,  \text{ }\forall x\in G \}$

Now I have to show that $p$ is a divisor of $\# \mathcal{Z}(G)$.

Hint: Write $G$ as a union of conjugacy classes $C_g$ and check that $C_{e}$ is not the only conjugacy class in $G$ that contains just one element.

Can somebody explain this exercise? How does the hint relate to the problem exactly? Should I use sylow theorems ?

Comment: Have you already studied actions of groups on sets, the orbit-stabilizer theorem and stuff? If so, have you seen that conjugation is an action of a group on itself?

Comment: Sylow is useless in this context. Something that you should ask yourself is: what is the conjugacy class of an element that commutes with every other element?

Comment: @DonAntonio: No, don't know. I know what conjugation is though

Comment: Sorry @MSKfdaswplwq, then my answer won't help you. Sylow theorems are useless here, imo...are you sure you weren't supposed to learn about group actions **before** trying to solve this question?

Comment: @DonAntonio Wait, is a 'group action' just the defined multiplication of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: No @MSKfdaswplwq...Try to read a little about it here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already know actions and stuff, define an action of $\;G\;$ on itself as follows

$$\forall\;g,x\in G\;,\;\;g\cdot x:=x^g:=x^{-1}gx$$

Check the above indeed is an action of $\,G\,$ on itself.

Since $\;\mathcal Orb(x)=[G:G_x]\;,\;\;G_x=Stab(x)=\{g\in G\;;\;x^g=x\}\;$ , then all the orbits have order a power of $\,p\,$.

Check that $\,x\in Z(G)\iff \mathcal Orb(x)=\{x\}\;$

We thus can write

$$|G|=\sum_{x\in G-Z(G)}'|\mathcal Orb(x)|+|Z(G)|$$

where $\;\sum'\,$ means sum over different, and thus disjoint, orbits.

Deduce that $\,p\mid|Z(G)|\;$ ...

Comment: What is Orb(x) ?

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq, Or(x) = the orbit of x . If you haven't studied actions of groups then my answer won't help you...yet I don't know any other elementary way  to solve your question. Of course, we could point that finite $\;p-$ groups are nilpotent and thus their center is non-trivial, but this is way more advanced than actions ansd stuff...

Comment: The things I know are groups, subgroups, homomorphisms/isomorphisms,  normal groups, conjugacy classes, index, cosets,  sylow theorem, quotient groups

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq, then I'm sorry: I can't help you with that. Perhaps someone else knows a basic way to prove this using what you know. I don't.

Comment: Thanks for you help anyway

Comment: So presumably you know that the size of the conjugacy class of an element $g \in G$ is $|G|/|C_G(g)|$, where $C_G(g)$ is the centralizer of $g$ in $G$? So the size of the conjugacy class of $g$ is divisible by $p$ unless $C_G(g)=G$ - that is, unless $g \in Z(G)$.